# Spring okta oauth2 properties using spring cloud vault

Tags: java, spring-boot, okta, spring-oauth2, spring-cloud-vault-config

We are using okta for authentication in our Spring boot project. We have successfully done authentication using java application as (refer - https://developer.okta.com/blog/2017/03/21/spring-boot-oauth)

Now what I am trying to do is move the okta clientId and secret property to vault.

Bootstrap for vault

> spring.cloud.vault:
>   host: localhost
>   port: 8200
>   scheme: http
>   token: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

Now please have a look at the below 2 cases for application properties

**Case 1 : properties used using @Value works**

> am.clientId=${account.clientId}
>   am.issuer=${account.issuer}

used as

> ```
> @Value("${am.clientId}")
> private String clientId;
> ```

```
@Value("${am.issuer}")
private String clientSecret;
```

**Case 2 : used as spring properties does not work** 
I use the same properties for spring oAuth and it fails

> okta.oauth2.clientId=${account.clientId}
>
> okta.oauth2.issuer=${account.issuer}

Exception log

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'account.clientId' in value "${account.clientId}"
>   account-web_1       |    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.parseStringValue(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:172) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>   account-web_1       |    at org.springframework.util.PropertyPlaceholderHelper.replacePlaceholders(PropertyPlaceholderHelper.java:124) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>   account-web_1       |    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.doResolvePlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:237) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]
>   account-web_1       |    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.resolveRequiredPlaceholders(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:211) ~[spring-core-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.5.RELEASE]

[Update]

So debugging the spring code I realised that the problem is only with property

> okta.oauth2.issuer

Github has one [issue](https://github.com/okta/okta-spring-boot/issues/23) regarding same, but the okta spring boot satarter 0.6.0 version still has issue.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting the `okta.oauth2.*` properties in your cloud config provider?  I usually test Cloud Config using a file repo, but from the client's perspective it should be the same. (I know this doesn't fully answer your question, but just want to make sure that works before continuing)

Comment: What I understand here is, you want me to set the properties in vault using following keys 

okta.oauth2.clientId
okta.oauth2.issuer. 

yes I have tried it, does not work. Looks like spring initializes the bean before the property values are resolved. I am not able to figure out which bean is being created by the spring, so that I can override it.

Comment: So I got it Brian Demers. this works if I add the following properties in the vault and remove them from the application properties 

okta.oauth2.clientId 
okta.oauth2.issuer

Answer (score 1):

So I have got one sollution to this one. Created a bean "oktaOAuth2Properties" to overrid the spring boot default bean and get the value from vault using the @Value annotation. the code looks like below. This works for me

> @Value("${okta.clientId}")
>       private String clientId;

```
@Value("${okta.issuer}")
private String issuer;

@Bean
public OktaOAuth2Properties oktaOAuth2Properties() {
    OktaOAuth2Properties properties = new OktaOAuth2Properties();
    properties.setClientId(clientId);
    properties.setIssuer(issuer);
    return properties;
}
```